# How to write a shared code between two classes

Tags: java, android, extends

In the below code, in class_1 and class_2 both extends from AbstractClass. I am trying when I call:

```
c1.setValid(5)
```

The following two lines, returns 5 as well:

```
System.out.println(c1.getValid());
System.out.println(c2.getValid());
```

pleas let me know how can I modify the Super class to achieve that.

**main**:

```
public class Main {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Class_1 c1 =  new Class_1();
    Class_2 c2 = new Class_2();

    System.out.println(c1.getValid());
    System.out.println(c2.getValid());

    c1.setValid(5);
    System.out.println(c1.getValid());
    System.out.println(c2.getValid());
}
}
```

**class_1**

```
public class Class_1 extends AbstractClass {

public Class_1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void setValid(int v) {
    SetValid(v);
}

public int getValid() {
    return GetValid();
}

}
```

**class_2**.:

```
public class Class_2 extends AbstractClass {

public Class_2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void setValid(int v) {
    SetValid(v);
}

public int getValid() {
    return GetValid();
}

}
```

**code**:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

public int isValid = -1;

public void SetValid(int value) {
    this.isValid = value;
}

public int GetValid() {
    return this.isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can delete setValid and  getValid from Class 1 and 2
and use  the parent's function SetValid and GetValid
If that is your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have all instances of your class to always have the same value, then you can simply use the `static` keyword.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public static int isValid = -1;

    ...

}
```

When `static` is used for a global variable, you're essentially declaring that this global variable will be shared by every instance of this class, including it's children.

Therefore, updating `isValid` with a new value in `Class_1` will cause `Class_2` to have the same value that `Class_1` updated.